# Android with Volley: Request not working anymore

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-networking

I'm trying to connect to my server using volley to register a new user. The code worked for only one time, I got a success response, but only once. I didn't change anything, just ran the app and provided different data.

The error I'm getting.

```
Unable to resolve url
```

The code I'm using, CustomRequest.java

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;

public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {
private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
private Map<String, String> params;

public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
                     Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                     Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
    return params;
};

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listener.onResponse(response);
}
}
```

SignupActivity.java

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
// POST Parameters
        params.put("api_key", API_KEY);
        params.put("email", etEmail.getText().toString());
        params.put("password", etPassword.getText().toString());
        params.put("verifyPassword", etConfirmPass.getText().toString());
        params.put("firstname", etFirstName.getText().toString());
        params.put("lastname", etLastName.getText().toString());
        params.put("birthday", birthDate);
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Method.POST, url, params, new Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "Worked?");
            }
        }, new ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error", "Nope");
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Manifest.xml has the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Can you upload your full source code with the real server Url so that I can check?

Comment: @BNK Thank you for replying, I tried usign my 3G connection and it worked, but not when using WiFi, I have no idea why!

Comment: Your wifi have any firewall or not? Not working but are there any logcat or response message available?

Comment: @BNK Yes, com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "<url>": No address associated with hostname
How can I know if my wifi has a firewall?

Comment: Ask the man who manage that network. Have you tried another Wifi yet?